# HDInsight Hive queries don't run

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I'm running Hive queries on an HDinsight cluster (specifically an HBase cluster). From some point in time I stopped getting responses to queries. They are all listed as "Initializing". Restarting Hive services on the Azure portal doesn't help, and starting the Hive metastore doesn't help either. Any ideas?

Comment: Microsoft has recently been made some changes to HDInsight and (especially North Europe region) and things were unstable for me in last couple of weeks. I would suggest creating a support ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: That could be it. It does look better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address this problem, every time it happens I connect remotely to the cluster and then run `stop_daemons` and `start_daemons`.

You can find these scripts in the `bin/` folder in your hive directory.